# In MySQL, what is SQL_PATH used for?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, the table information_schema.SCHEMATA has information about databases. There's a field SQL_PATH that is always NULL, according to the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.5/en/schemata-table.html

My question is, what is this field for? I see that it is a varchar(512). That is a lot of wasted potential for descriptions or other metadata for databases. Can I use this field, change it, etc, for some description metadata for my databases?

Comment: *"what is this field for?"* No idea, might be for future use? As MySQL is owned by Oracle corp -> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch2.htm  there are some things defined there as `ORACLE_PATH`, `PATH` and `SQLPATH` which might be related..

Comment: *"That is a lot of wasted potential for descriptions or other metadata for databases"*  Maybe if you have 100.000 databases yes otherwise not really still with that amount you only wasted around 50 Mb disk storage/RAM as information_schema is loading into RAM when the server is running..  *"Can I use this field, change it, etc, for some description metadata for my databases?"* No unless you edit and recompile the source code then it would be possible..

Comment: if you are looking to at comments you need to make them on table level ... The [CREATE TABLE..](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) has a `COMMENT` section on table/column/partition level..   Offcource existing tables can changed with comment with ALTER there is a COMMENT option there aswell

Comment: @RaymondNijland, your responses are valid. Please mark it as an answer so you can get credit.